# How to debug NSPreferencePane in Xcode 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I need to debug an NSPreferencePane I am working on using XCode 5 I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help with how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated ?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain little bit more what you wanted to achieve

Answer (score 1):

With a debugger you can either start the program you want to debug, or attach to a running process. As the preference pane is loaded from a host application, you'll need to do the latter.

In gdb, for example, if you know the pid for the process you can call: -

```
 attach <pid>
```

In XCode, go to the Debug menu and select "Attach to Process" and choose the host application which loads your NSPreferencePane.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to attach the debugger to the NSPreferencePane and instead used NSLog statements that I was then able to read using the Console application in OSX. Hope this will help anyone who has this issue in the future.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Use NSAlert to show alert wherever you wanted to log a message.